# Why does passing a function return value makes useState() initialization only run once?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState(
        console.log("State initialization")
    )
```

The code above runs on every state change

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState(
        () => console.log("State initialization")
    )
```

While this one only runs only once, when the code is run

What does the function have to do on making it only run once?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with console.log initial state???

Comment: @Evren Just a sample code so I could understand how this works

Answer (score 1):

`useState` uses initialization argument only once on component mount. Then it's ignored. But in the first case, you're passing an expression, not a function and it's run every time (and its result is only values at the first mount).

P. S. `console.log` doesn't return anything, so in the second case value will be `undefined`.